# Upload asset failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: assets

When I try to upload an image, I am getting the following error:

imagepng(C:/wamp/craft/storage/runtime/temp/assets53ebcb012cffa3.92019251-temp.png): failed to open stream: Invalid argument (C:\wamp\craft\app\vendor\imagine\imagine\lib\Imagine\Gd\Image.php:691)

Do you know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the permissions and make sure that Craft has write permissions to the craft/storage folder first.

Comment: I am running craft on my Windows local machine using WAMP .. what permissions do I need to check? Craft is writing cache files in the storage and saving the image in the temp folder shown

Comment: Curious... what the original file name for the image?

Comment: it was flat.png .. but it must have been something strange because it did not happen again and I did not change anything in my server config